# Firebase: difference between data retrieved via firebase.db().ref('myRef') and firebase.db.ref('myRef').once('value', callback)

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Whats the difference between the data received from a direct call to a ref as in:

`console.log(firebase.db().ref('categories'))`

versus data received via dataSnapShot in the value event as in:

```
firebase.db().ref('categories').once('value', snapShot => {
       console.log(snapShot)
})
```

As I tested the value of `key` property is the same in either methods of accessing data,

`console.log(firebase.db().ref('categories').key)`

returns the same key as returned in the following:

```
firebase.db().ref('categories').once('value', snapShot => {
       console.log(snapShot.key)
})
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`firebase.db().ref('categories')` is just a reference to the "categories" point in your database.

It does not contain the data that is stored in the database. Creating such objects does not involve any communication with the database at all.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference

Doing `once('value', callback)` on a reference initiates the communication. The actual data from the referenced point is passed to the `callback` as a "data snapshot".

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot

Both References and DataSnapshots have the `key` property: the Reference knows where it's pointing to, and the DataSnapshot knows where it came from.